# Pandas (bug in 0.14?) Int64Index: "intersection" with repeated indexes

Tags: python, pandas, intersection

This sounds like a stupid question, but what is the semantics of pandas `Int64Index.intersection`? I thought it was just supposed to intersect the two sets, either with or without repetition; but see the examples below. I am using pandas 0.14.1.

**Update**: this looks like a bug in pandas. Note that it raises exception in `0.13`: it was not permitted to intersect indexes with duplicate values.

**UPDATE**: ***this bug appears to be fixed in pandas 0.15***. Also the release notes for 0.15 mention various issues with duplicate indexes.

Example:

```
>>> pd.Int64Index([8,4,8]).intersection(pd.Int64Index([5]))
Int64Index([8], dtype='int64')
>>> pd.Int64Index([3,4,8]).intersection(pd.Int64Index([5]))
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

Why is it that when I intersect `8, 4, 8` with `5`, I get `8`? It has something to do with repeating values:

```
>>> pd.Int64Index([1,1,2]).intersection(pd.Int64Index([3]))
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
>>> pd.Int64Index([2,1,1]).intersection(pd.Int64Index([3]))
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

**UPDATE**

I am looking at `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py(1318)get_indexer_non_unique()`.
First it gets to line `1086`, since there are duplicates.

```
   1081         try:
   1082             indexer = self.get_indexer(other.values)
   1083             indexer = indexer.take((indexer != -1).nonzero()[0])
   1084         except:
   1085             # duplicates
-> 1086             indexer = self.get_indexer_non_unique(other.values)[0].unique()
   1087 
   1088         taken = self.take(indexer)
   1089         if self.name != other.name:
   1090             taken.name = None
```

At this point

```
ipdb> p self
Int64Index([2, 2, 1], dtype='int64')
ipdb> p other
Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

Then this function returns, in line `1319`,

```
1  1318         indexer, missing = self._engine.get_indexer_non_unique(tgt_values)
-> 1319         return Index(indexer), missing
```

This is what it returns:

```
ipdb> p indexer
array([-1])
ipdb> p missing
array([0])
```

After that the indexer is applied to get the last element of the array. Why? No idea.

Actually, in the same file it says

```
def get_indexer_non_unique(self, target, **kwargs):
    """ return an indexer suitable for taking from a non unique index
        return the labels in the same order as the target, and
        return a missing indexer into the target (**missing are marked as -1
        in the indexer**); target must be an iterable """
```

So missing is `-1`, but then it is used to extract the last element. Is it a bug in Pandas? It seems pretty dramatic, and I am relying on this `intersection` all over the place. Is it always including the last element for good measure?

Comment: this was fixed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8374 (which is in 0.15.0), so maybe you are quoting some older code?

Comment: Yes, it works in `0.15`, but not in `0.14`. I just did not expect a bug in such basic functionality. By the way, the upgrade to `0.15.1` was somewhat annoying, as pandas now raises `TypeError` every time `DataFrame.loc[ list_of_indexes] ` does not have any of the indexes in it.

Comment: well, you hit an edge case. Bugs happen. That's why pandas releases new versions. ``.loc`` shouldn't raise a ``TypeError``, but a ``KeyError``, unless you are passing invalid data (which a ``list_of_indexes`` is. You can pass list of indices, not a list_of_indexes. Doesn't make much sense. If you think its a bug open a bug-report on github.